# Create a File Browser & Picker using Recycler View in Android as a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to create a file Browser & Picker inside a viewPager Fragment that will display the sd card files and let user pick a file from it. It has to be created using a RecyclerView and not a list view. Kindly tell me how do I do it. Kindly give me about how or what code should I write for this.

I want something like this :-

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VLEl.jpg)

But it should be inside a RecyclerView. I have no idea how to do this as I am a newbie in android development. Kindly help. Thankyou !

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

this is a good tutorial to do this, it's a french tutorial but you can understand it :

https://openclassrooms.com/courses/creez-des-applications-pour-android/tp-un-explorateur-de-fichiers

Comment: It's the ListView implementation what i am looking for is making it with a recycler view. Thanks anyways. :)